# Assign author to category and not only posts

Tags: categories, author

Is it possible to assign an author as a writer for a category? I know that authors are mainly for posts/pages, but my client has a site structure where the categories basically act as pages.

I could of course solve this by using ACF, but is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

By default WordPress does not support an author on categories or any other taxonomy as can be seen in the [database structure](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Database_Diagram). You can certainly add that association through taxonomy term meta data, but you will of course be responsible for all management and display of that custom data (unless you can find a plugin out there which will handle it for you).